# Scaling Path draw in Swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui

currently working on view drawn by Path and i need to make this view scale when got landscape mode and ignore safe area but nothing happened and what i need is that the orange view cover the view

```
struct BottomRoundShape: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(){
            Color.green.ignoresSafeArea()
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX , y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.midY))
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.midY))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX, y:UIScreen.main.bounds.midY), control: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.midY+150))

        }.fill(
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.init(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.6, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1)),.init(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705882, green: 0.262745098, blue: 0.1529411765, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
        ).shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4745098039, green: 0.4745098039, blue: 0.4745098039, alpha: 1)), radius: 15).ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `Shape`. You can then used the `rect` passed in instead so it uses the correct `CGRect` depending on the device orientation.

Example:

```
struct BottomRoundShape: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green.ignoresSafeArea()

            CustomShape()
                .fill(
                    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.init(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.6, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1)),.init(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705882, green: 0.262745098, blue: 0.1529411765, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                )
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4745098039, green: 0.4745098039, blue: 0.4745098039, alpha: 1)), radius: 15)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct CustomShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX , y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.midY))
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.midY))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY), control: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY+150))
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]